# Can anyone ID this ship, please?

Tags: set-identification

None of this looks familiar to me, but its incredibly complicated. A LEGO set or fan-made?
Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

<s>Not a LEGO set.</s> *Following up on details in comments it appears that [Dcbarkley](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/15013/dcbarkley) has managed to identify pictured model as a LEGO set thanks to this answer. However, my initial (wrong) assumption was based on dark color of the bricks used in the model. Picking up quite unique piece for cross-checking eventually led to correct set identification. Below you will find original answer:*

Confirmed with [Slope, Curved 5 x 8 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15625#T=C). It appears to be used in Black, however there's no set produced to have these slopes in Black. In case Dark Bluish Gray was used in the model, then still, none of the sets having this slope look like your model.

[image]

Comment: It is dark grey. The item is some damaged. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you check URL I've shared you can see this part doesn't exist as LEGO in Dark Gray.

Comment: Found it! It's light grey and from Star Wars Imperial Assault Carrier. Set is heavily stained. Never would have identified without your piece help. Thanks!

Comment: I would have never guessed this is Light Bluish Gray colored set.